# How can I make a post base support fenceposts (gateposts) on top of concrete?

Tags: fence, gate-post

I'm preparing to add a railing on top of a high concrete (-filled cinderblock) retaining wall at the boundary of my property. But while I was at it, I thought it might be nice to add a higher and more secure fence gate between the wall and my house.

There happens to be a concrete slab next to the house for the outdoor A/C unit, so I thought securing the strike post to that rather than digging and adding even more concrete would be easier and just as secure. But now that I've started, I'm not so sure.

[image]

Here's what I have so far: one (future) strike post, secured to the slab with a Simpson E-Z Base Fence Post Base, the pivot post secured (a bit better now that I know a bit more about what I'm doing) to the top of the retaining wall, and an in-process gate kit. I'd looked at some other post bracket options, but this is the only one Simpson had that didn't come with a warning that the top needed to be secured (eg: to prevent rotation). With 4 bolts anchored into the concrete, I'm pretty sure no rotation is happening.

[image: Unfenced gap with post]

[image: Post base closeup]

[image: Gate in-progress]

The problem is these things aren't as ...er... *easy* to use as the name would imply. Hammer drills aren't exactly precision tools, and if you don't get the 4 holes lined up just right, either the brace won't slide on over the bolts, or you'll have to redrill and the anchor won't stay down. Also, if the post itself doesn't fit in the base snugly, it will wobble inside the base.

I'm wondering if better options are available for this kind of project, both in alternate post base products, and in alternate post attachment schemes. By "better" I mean much easier to implement properly, and/or more likely to last long-term.

For instance, I saw that Simpson had [another product](https://www.strongtie.com/nonstandoffpostbases_postbases/ub_bracket/p/ub) for attaching fence posts to concrete for fences, but (suspiciously), its only available in Canada. [Here's another](https://highlandfasteners.com/product/fencemate-swift-clamp-bolt-down-post-support-4-x-4-100-x-100mm-galvanised) I found that looks like it has a way to deal with the post-fit issue, but seems to only be for sale in the UK.

I've also seen some solutions that braced the posts against the side of the retaining wall, and I suppose it wouldn't be the worst idea in the world to dig *next to* the retaining wall on the high side and sink some more concrete around posts, as that might act like a bit of a deadman for the wall too. I'd have to make sure to attach it to the wall somehow though, as the ground next to this wall has a distinct tendency to settle a bit.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147113/discussion-on-question-by-t-e-d-how-can-i-make-a-post-base-support-fenceposts); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.